# If every linear map $A \to B$ is an algebra-homomorphism then $A=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $A$ be an associative algebra over a field. Is the following statement true and if so what would the argument be?

> If all linear maps $A \to B$ are also homomorphisms of algebras for all associative algebras $B$ over the same field, then $A=0$.

The point of this question is to prove that $T(A) \cong A \iff A=0$ where $T(A)$ denotes the tensor algebra of $A$.

Comment: An associative algebra over *what*? A ring? A field?

Comment: $$
T(A) = \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}A^{\otimes n} = \mathbb{K} \oplus A \oplus A^{\otimes 2} \oplus A^{\otimes 3} \cdots.
$$

Comment: @morrowmh Over a field. I edited it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde How does it prove that? I mean that shows that it intuitively correct but it is not enough I think. And I would rather want to see if the above statement is true because it seems to be an interesting question

Comment: Does your definition of "algebra" include a unit?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Yes

Comment: By convention $T^0(A)$ is the ground field itself. So I suppose you want $T(A)=K$? Your question does not need the tensor algebra. I only made the comment, because you said that "it is the point of this question".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ah, I understand. Well, then this is pretty trivial, true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the setting of algebras with unit, any algebra map must send $1 \mapsto 1$. If the zero map $A \to A$ (which is certainly linear) is an algebra map, then it sends $1 \mapsto 0$, and therefore $1 = 0$ in $A$, so $A=0$.

Comment: Do you think it could be extended to algebras without unit?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised, but I haven't thought about it.